# Sympy Lambdify get 3d plot for 2d equation in mayavi

Tags: python, sympy, mayavi

```
  str_exp="x+y"
  expr = sympify((str_expr))
  X,Y,Z=np.ogrid[x_start:x_end:no_x_points , y_start:y_end:no_y_points , z_start:z_end:no_z_points]
  f = lambdify((x,y,z), expr)
  foo=f(X,Y,Z)
```

Even though `expr` is a function of `x` and `y`, I expect `foo` to produce 3d data as z is being varied too. When I try to plot `foo` using mayavi, a single line is being plotted instead of a plane.

I am sure that it is a consequence of sympy's `lamdify` as the dimension of `foo` is `(100,100,1)` when `expr` is `x+y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem would be that `expr` would have only 2 variables and hence you wouldn't get the 3d array as required. 
So, sympy's sympify function doesn't simplify the expression (or string given). So, you can add `"(z+1)**2 - z*z - 2*z - 1"` (or some simple expression such that the z term doesn't cancel out) to  `str_exp` if you don't have `'z'` term in it.

So this way sympify would return you an expression with z.

```
>>str_expr="x+y+(z+1)**2 - z*z - 2*z - 1"
>>sympify((str_expr))
x + y - z**2 - 2*z + (z + 1)**2 - 1
```

Comment: Yeah, this would work. But I am looking for a more elegant way of directing sympy to give a result with the correct dimensions based on the number of parameters(variables) given.